# Ошибка при создании виртуальной среды в python

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

Пытаюсь создать виртуальную среду в python (на windows 7) и вылезает ошибка: Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почитал в интернете, говорят, что проблема может быть в переменной PATH + в неправильной установке python. Python у меня установлен в двух местах:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как решить проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создавать виртуальное окружение следующей командой:

```
$ virtualenv venv
```

Comment: О, спасибо большое! Это то, что мне нужно!

Comment: @Chudvan Если вам помог мой ответ, то пожалуйста, отметьте его.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга.
Хех, как только - так сразу.